# contentKey character restrictions in Salesforce CMS upload?

Tags: experience-cloud, salesforce-cms

I'm doing bulk uploads of content to Salesforce CMS.  Many of my records went in with urlName defined in the JSON, but because that's causing issues due to invalid characters (which I am not clear on what those invalid characters are), I am now omitting the field.  From what I understand, a reupload of the same content will overwrite the current content matching it.  I assume this match is based on contentKey.  I have not attempted to define contentKey in the upload JSON, but I am concerned that it is beholden to the same unknown character restrictions as urlName - does anyone know if this is the case, and if so, what those character restrictions are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contentKey is defined by Salesforce themselves when the CMS entry is created and is returned in the success JSON sent in an email.  There is not a way to obtain the contentKey outside of what's sent in that email.